# Modify custom made cells from storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, storyboard

I have an iOS app with a lot of static cells (for a preferences view), so it makes sense to put all of that in storyboard, but I would like to be able to add a checkmark to them based on if the preference is set or not.

I have my delegate method setup

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

}
```

I just can't figure out how to "grab" the cell from the interface builder using the indexpath so that I can decide programmatically whether or not I should add a checkmark. I have a feeling there is some sort of superclass/delegate method I can call, but I'm not sure what it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use static cells, you need to put them in a `UITableViewController` because there's magic going in there. Under the hood, it implements those data source methods for you. But you can override them. The important thing is that you need to call the super version to let it do it's job. If the method returns a value you need to return that too.

So in your case:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    let isChecked = true // put your logic to determine whether the cell should be checked here
    cell.accessoryType = isChecked ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone
    // ...
    return cell
}
```